# ezpublish backend pushing to wordpress frontend

Tags: wordpress, push, ezpublish

I have this problem that our primary news site is already running on wordpress. Due to the editorial workflows and some new projects, i am checking ezpublish. But I want to keep wordpress frontend and want to attach it to ezpublush. So content that gets generated in ezpub can be published live into wordpress. I find extensions are very limited so wondering has anything been worked upon this direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to keep on using Wordpress for your frontend, what about using the REST API to retrieve content from its content repository ?

The REST API provided by the eZ Engineering is just awesome so most of your work will be to develop something on the Wordpress side which will be able to get connected to this API (I don't know WP enough to say if it's something easy or not).

Another solution if you don't want to use the REST API, is to use an XML template in place of the default HTML one. This way, eZ Publish will expose its contents over XML which is more usable than pure HTML...

Pro for the REST API : very fast (in comparison of using the XML solution)
Cons for the REST API : need to develop something dedicated to this WP/eZ bridge on the WP side

Pro for the XML solution : maybe more simple since I'm pretty sure that there are some extension on the WP side which are able to import contents based on XML
Cons : see REST API's Pro

Answer (score 3):

The easiest option would be to configure an rss export from eZ and import that rss into WP objects. However I agree with Doug that you would be best using this as a temporary solution with the plan being to replace the Wordpress front end with an eZ front end.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if it's obvious, but I'd suggest that you do an estimate of moving the design and content to ez so as to establish how much work you can afford to sink into this push idea.

I think that you should look at the workflow support in ez and the onpublish trigger. This will let you hook the content as it's being published in ez and push into wp. The model is going to have some edge cases since the content structure in ez is quite flexible. For example, you're going to need to make some choices about related content, embedded content and images.